# Submitting a form with onsubmit attribute with python

Tags: python, html, forms

I am trying to submit a form through python and I send a urllib request with a url like
https://example.com/form_submitted?element_1=data

It worked on another form but this one contains `onsubmit` attribute in the form tag and it only redirects me to the form page with the input field filled with data and if I click the submit button, it works.

I also tried https://example.com/form_submitted?element_1=data&submit=Submit but it didn't work. What can I do?

```
<form id="form_1" method="post" action="form_submitted" onsubmit>
    <label for="element_1">Text</label>
    <div>
        <input id="element_1" name="element_1" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/> 
    </div>
    <input id="saveForm" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```